# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [ExpressionEngine® Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit of feedback as to how this site is going, and when we may expect to exit beta. Anna asked this 6 months ago and we were told it "won't be long" :) http://meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1230/150

Comment: @AdrianMacneil I can't promise when the work will be done, but Expression Engine SE is in our graduation queue. It's just a matter of when we can get a design and a rather big backlog at the moment. I didn't want to announce this until I had a better idea of when the date would be closer - but yeah, you definitely made it, this is a really nice site.

Comment: Great news! Given that we are a community of web designers, I'm sure we could help out by crowdsourcing some designs here too (at least to come up with some ideas to help your team).

Comment: Congrats, thanks Adrian and everyone who's contributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can I revoke or regenerate an expressionengine license number?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/can-i-revoke-or-regenerate-an-expressionengine-license-number)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I redirect from a User Message Template](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18755/how-do-i-redirect-from-a-user-message-template)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Custom Change Password Page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/custom-change-password-page)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [WYGWAM Hangs (504 Gateway Time-out) when adding apostrophe](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18622/wygwam-hangs-504-gateway-time-out-when-adding-apostrophe)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Search in Grid field - Relationship](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/search-in-grid-field-relationship)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Uninstall Module via Database Query EE1-EE2 upgrade](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18456/uninstall-module-via-database-query-ee1-ee2-upgrade)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Restoring Category Groups and Categories?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18205/restoring-category-groups-and-categories)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [now() function redeclared](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/now-function-redeclared)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [how to redirect back 2 pages after add to cart in Cart Throb](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/how-to-redirect-back-2-pages-after-add-to-cart-in-cart-throb)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Parent Relationship and Channel Category Archive](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18658/parent-relationship-and-channel-category-archive)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---