# Status of our beta

Tags: support

Can we can get feedback on how our site is doing from the folks who decide if a site is launched out of beta?

We've been at this for ~1.5 years now as a community. Surely, "beta" phase has some end and doesn't go on forever.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site *is* in the graduation queue, it's just awaiting a design, which is probably going to entail some collaboration with the folks behind EE.

Pound for pound, this is an *extremely* strong site, you've achieved respectable amounts of participation consistently, and there's obviously a very vibrant community here. Just be patient, it's just a matter of time before our design team can get to it.

Jin or someone else from the design team will post some concepts here once they're ready, then get feedback / make adjustments, and it's *go go go* :)

**Update** - This is getting closer. I don't believe work *has* started on it yet, but I'm pretty certain you're close to the top of the queue. Hang tight. In the meanwhile, you could have a discussion about the 'third item' you want for your top user swag. Each site gets shirts, sticker and a 'third' branded item that uniquely fits your community. Go ahead and open a meta question to have a little fun as you wait, if you want.

Comment: Cheers Tim - I think we all appreciate you keeping us up to date.

Comment: Thank you for the info Tim

Comment: Tim... Your edit was pointed out to me but I don't fully understand what the swag is... Where is that given out? What are our options?

Answer (score 3):

I know you're asking for official feedback here, but thought I'd re-post Stack Exchange Community Manager [Tim Post's comment from March 12, 2014.](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/lets-get-critical-mar-2014-site-self-evaluation#comment359_1255)

> I can't promise when the work will be done, but Expression Engine SE
>   is in our graduation queue. It's just a matter of when we can get a
>   design and a rather big backlog at the moment. I didn't want to
>   announce this until I had a better idea of when the date would be
>   closer - but yeah, you definitely made it, this is a really nice site.

Sort of official, and definitely promising.

Comment: This helps for sure! Thank you for posting Alex. I hadn't seen this comment. Promising.

Comment: Please do not use the backward American date style. It's extremely confusing.